# wsgateway failed to send message to channel '' within timeout: -1 in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

**I got this error.**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send message to channel 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel@261b0001' within timeout: -1
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:199)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
```

And my spring integration xml is like this.

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="asmTestWSGateway" request-channel="webserviceInboundChannel" 
    reply-channel="outboundStartChannel" marshaller="asmMarshaller"
        unmarshaller="asmMarshaller" />

    <bean id="asmMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="targetClasses" value="com.sds.redca.test.vo.DependencyVO"></property>
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:mapping-asm.xml"></property>  
    </bean> 
<int:chain input-channel="webserviceInboundChannel" output-channel="checkAuthentificationChannel">
        <int:service-activator> 
            <bean class="com.sds.redca.core.endpoint.activator.BuildMsgActivator" /> 
        </int:service-activator>
        <int:filter ref="sampleFilter" />
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="protocolType" value="#{T(com.sds.redca.cmm.RedCAConstants).WS_PROTOCOL}"/>
        </int:header-enricher>              
    </int:chain>    

    <int:chain input-channel="checkAuthentificationChannel" output-channel="outboundStartChannel">
        <int:service-activator> 
            <bean class="com.sds.redca.core.endpoint.activator.AuthentificationServiceActivator" /> 
        </int:service-activator>
    </int:chain>
```

Webservice gateway received soap message with marshalled message translated to vo object.
and normalized and checked whether or not it is valid then go to back to the reply channel for returning the client.

I don't know how to solve this. Even if I make logging level debug, i can't find the reason.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Show, please, your `outboundStartChannel` config.

Tipically `failed to send message to channel ... within timeout: -1` is happened, when we use `QueueChannel` and can't overcome its current `capacity`, becuase there is not enough resources to `poll` messages from that queue to process.

Actoually I don't see reason for your use-case to use `reply-channel` on `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` at all. Just remove it and `output-channel="outboundStartChannel"` from the last `<chain>` as well. And rely on the `TemporaryReplyChannel` from the `MessageHeaders` in that case to achieve a `short circuit` for the entire flow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved after changing the name of outbound  channel. Still, I don't why I got this error. There was no other channel that use same name.